# How can I insert a path node into svg tag with React

Tags: reactjs, svg

```
let whichone=1;
const tmpPath=(index)=>{
  return <path className={`bottom-logo_b1`} d={`svg1`} />
};
```

// if there are multi paths. is it right?

// `className={'bottom-logo_b${index}'} d={'svg${index}'}`

and my true question is

```
...
return (
  <div className={"bottomlogo-wrap"}>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox={"0 0 " + w1 + " " + h1}>
      <g id={"btmlogo_in"} data-name={"btmlogo_in"}>
        <tmpPath index={whichone} />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
);
```

it doesn't work with this line: `<tmpPath index={whichone} />`

Comment: call tmpPath as function. 
 <g id={'btmlogo_in'} data-name={'btmlogo_in'}>
           {tmpPath(whichone)}
  </g>

Comment: `'svg1'` is not a valid value for the `d` attribute of a `<path>` element

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky thanks for reminding me . it`s just a varchar not a string~
@abidh thanks it works!